# Design patterns to make a component extendible, pluggable without making changes to the system that it is attached to

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, software-design

*What are the best **Design Patterns** that can be used here to address the business requirements mentioned below?*

Lets say we have a business requirement to create a single dashboard that can be easily used for different Vehicles such as **Car** , **Boat** and a **Plane** with minimal changes, hence we will need a centralized interface that can be easily customized to communicate both ways with the underlying system ( e.g to gather the info on speed, battery, depth, altitude, heat and functionalities like, turn, accelerate, start, stop, brake etc). Dashboard should come with Gauges etc which talk to **something** that again talks to the underlying hardware

Obvious solution is to break down the problem into components (see below), such that minimal changes are required when switching vehicles. in the following solution only the concrete implementation of CentralController needs to be different per vehicle, however what if you have hunders of components to communicate with in a car and then you map all those types to our Application related types, such as HeatInfo used by the HeatGauge might contain info coming from inside, outside and from the engine, hence we are talking to different components in a vehicle and that might differ per vehicle, what are the best practices to go about addressing data mapping here?

- Panel with gauges
- CentralController{ get /set }.  CentralControllerImpl
- Vehicle and its components

So it boils down to:

**What are the Design patterns out there for creating a simplified API on top of multiple complex API's**

---

Since some of you think the question is vague i will post the real problem here

i have worked on a app that talks to very complex peace of hardware that controls hunders of varieties of sensors and controls, the app i am working on only exposes a few functionalities relevent for some human role responsible for that part.

you should see the hardware being a very complex and large database of information that you manipulate, and the app i am working on only exposes a little information, however that information might need to read hunderds of tables and compile all that information into my view related domain objects, the component that actually does the mapping has been made generic such that the future applications can leverage from it.

and i want to know from you guys what are the best Design patterns out there which can be used to create that generic component easy to work with and extended if required ?

e.g. Visitor + MVC is the most obvious

Comment: This is almost definitely homework and also very vague I might add. Are you actually coding this interface or just writing up some high level description of it?

Comment: haha, i just wanted to present the problem in a easy way, i guess i am not very good at it.

Comment: usually "complex system with only a few needed api's" hints at the facade pattern

Comment: Thats it, jeff **"Facade"** is the right answer to this :), too bad you didnt post this as a answer, i would have accepted it.

Comment: This should be in http://programmers.stackexchange.com I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your requirements are too broad for a [single pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern).  While Visitor, MVC, and Facade may all play a part in the overall design, you are describing a system at a much higher and complex level.  Patterns are useful to describe a set of common behaviors and to facilitate communication but if the approach to using them is "I'm looking for a silver bullet" then the effort will lead to frustation and disappointment with patterns taking the undeserved blame.

How about a design where modules work together using a set of patterns which make it easier to integrate individual elements into a framework provides for the display of components from a general toolbox which are then customized for the specific use case being implemented. Your analogy with a dashboard has been used as a starting place many times because it a useful design approach.

For example,

- Dashboard: Framework to display gauges using **Facade** for the display, **Front Controller** to provide an interface for types of controls/gauges, and maybe **Blackboard**  for cases where gauges need to coordinate
- Gauge: **Module** to help provide a framework of components, **Visitor** if you need generic call-back behavior, **Observer** or **Publish/Subscribe** if you need async communications, with **State** as possibility if the display element that needs to hold over time.

Comment: Your right Kelly, this cant be solved with a single pattern, i am refactoring the app. i will let you know how it goes.

Comment: I like the question even though it was closed. You should ask it again but word it like, "I'm choosing between pattern X and pattern Y for this behavior. The list of pros and cons for each that I can see are A/B/C, etc. I'm leaning towards pattern (X/Y), have I overlooked something?"  Another option is to ask this on the Programmers stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

If classes has no differences in data and behavior, why do you need to create different classes? Maybe will be enogh to create single class: **Vehicle**?
There no complex problem in requirements, so it seems you do not need patterns.

Comment: A generic dashboard for a variable number of gauges of unknown capabilities and inputs in only a single class?  Really? That's a recipe for a [Big Ball of Mud](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_ball_of_mud)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest looking into a [Builder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) design pattern and combining it with [Bridge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_pattern).

Comment: That can be used for the Panel itself, however not good for the generic component that actually does the data mapping.

Comment: Usually, for UIs bridge and builder are combined. (see Patterns in Java book)